# Lodash & Underscore "each" over localStorage gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, local-storage, each, lodash

I noticed something odd when trying to switch over a custom `for` `in` loop to a `underscore` or `lodash` loop.

> JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/manerotoru/2/edit?html,js,console

```
window.localStorage.setItem("hello", "world")

console.log('-----underscore-----')

_.each(window.localStorage, function (value, key) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(key);
});


console.log('-----custom-----')

function each (object, callback) {
  for (var key in object) {
    var value = object[key];
    callback(value, key);
  }
}

each(window.localStorage, function (value, key) {              
  console.log(value);
  console.log(key);
});
```

Here's what's logged to the console.

```
-----lodash-----
undefined
0
-----custom-----
world
hello
```

And it's not that `_.each` doesn't loop over objects, because it does it just fine here.

```
var data = {"hello": "world"}

_.each(data, function (value, key) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(key);
});
```

Is there any reason why I can't use `_.each` from either library to loop over `localStorage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue that won't be fixed. You can find [the bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/297).

The underlying problem seems to be that underscore's `_.each()` doesn't cope well with objects that have a `length` property.

Official response from the bug report:

> The final decision is that you should iterate `localStorage` yourself, and not rely on `_.each`.